# Unrar WinRar 5.5 archives in C#

Tags: c#, .net, rar, sharpcompress

In July 2017 WinRar released version 5.5 which made changes to the rar standard. Since then, our library of choice, [SharpCompress](https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress), fails with any archives produced by that version:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot determine compressed stream type. Supported Archive Formats: Zip, GZip, Tar, Rar, 7Zip
  at SharpCompress.Archive.ArchiveFactory.Open (System.IO.Stream stream, SharpCompress.Common.Options options) [0x00104] in <c75ca43fe8b84e939decf36d5e9b045b>:0
  at ImporterProject.Program+<ImportDemo>c__async1.MoveNext () [0x005d9] in <131bee082c1a48da8a91db5359e262cc>:0
```

An example of a new archive can be downloaded [here](https://www.hltv.org/matches/2321778/bravado-vs-mostly-harmless-esea-main-season-27-north-america). 7zip opens this file without probelms, which is why I know that the archive is not broken.

What other libraries are there that support reading of rar-archives in .NET? Optimally, the library should work on mono/FreeBSD in addition to Windows.

Comment: I have developed something that works for our usecase, but isn't that great in general: https://gist.github.com/moritzuehling/fb371e20d93569271481a9a4f74a024b
It requires unrar (on linux/bsd) or 7zip (on windows) to be installed.

Comment: __win.rar GmbH__ releases not only the __WinRAR__ package, but also the free to use library `UnRAR.dll` and even the free to use `UnRAR` source code at [RARLAB - Extras](https://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm). The documentation of the archive file format is also available for download by every developer who wants to extract RAR archives of any format with a self-made application.